# How can I make this fold more generic

Tags: haskell, fold

I've written this function:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
module Hierarchy where

import           Control.Applicative
import qualified Control.Foldl       as CF
import           Control.Foldl (Fold(..))
import           Control.Lens hiding (Fold)
import qualified Data.Foldable       as F
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy       as M
import           Data.Monoid         (Monoid (..), Sum (Sum))
import           Data.Profunctor
import           Data.Set (Set)
import           Data.Maybe
import           Data.Text           (Text)

overMaps :: (Ord k) => Fold a b -> Fold (M.Map k a) (M.Map k b)
overMaps (Fold step begin done) = Fold step' M.empty (fmap done)   
  where
  step' acc m = M.foldrWithKey insert acc m
  insert k el acc = M.insert k (step (fromMaybe begin $ M.lookup k acc) el) acc
```

I feel like I'm missing some fundamental abstraction that could make this more general, and more succinct.

Can anyone give me some pointers as to how I could use any modern Haskellisms here to make this better?

**edit** The code is here https://github.com/boothead/hierarchy/blob/master/src/Hierarchy.hs

and I've included the imports

**edit** Perhaps I can use ifoldr to get closer to @cdk's idea?

**edit**

Here's the closest I've got.

```
--overFoldable :: (Ord k) => Fold a b -> Fold (M.Map k a) (M.Map k b)
overFoldable :: (Ord i, At (f i a), FoldableWithIndex i (f i), Monoid (f i x))
             => Fold a b -> Fold (f i a) (f i b)
overFoldable (Fold step begin done) = Fold step' mempty (fmap done)
  where
  step' acc m = Lens.ifoldr insert acc m
  insert k el acc = Lens.at k %~ return . flip step el . fromMaybe begin $ acc
```

Here the first (commented) type signature works. Now the problem lies in the existential `x` in the type signature of `Fold :: (x -> a -> x) -> x -> (x -> b) -> Fold a b` I can't figure out what to put in the `begin` position of my new fold. It needs to be of Type `f i x` but I don't know how to tell Haskell how to take `x` to be the same type as `begin`.

Comment: I can't find a typeclass `Fold` in Hoogle.

Comment: @SebastianRedl It's in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl, I believe

Comment: At a glance, `overMaps :: Foldable f => Fold a b -> Fold (f a) (f b)` almost looks promising. Unfortunately I think `foldrWithKey` is the sticking point as it's not part of the `Foldable` class

Comment: Perhaps not entirely germane to your question, but `fromMaybe begin $ M.lookup ...` can be implemented with `M.findWithDefault`

Comment: @cdk Yes this is what I was getting at, I wonder if I could use one of the Indexed* things in Lens?

Answer (score 4):

Mainly for my own understanding (and that of my beloved [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)):

Suppose I have a Fold `sumLengths` that adds the lengths of strings (so `fold sumLengths ["a","bbb"]` yields 4)

I want `overMaps sumLengths` to be a Fold that takes say a French and a Dutch dictionary, and makes a new dictionary `D` such that
`lookup D "bread"` is 9 (`length("pain") + length("brood")`)

The problem of course is that some words may not occur in all dictionaries: `lookup D "sex"` is `length("sexe")` as we Dutch are very prudish :-)
So we need the `begin` value of our fold not only at the beginning of our fold, but possibly at any moment.

This means it won't do to just lift the `step` function to `Map k` (in that case we could use any instance of `Applicative` instead of our
 `Map`, see below), we have to take our `begin` value all along the way.

This "`lift` plus default value" is the member `fuseWith` of a new class `Fusable` below. It is the  `step'` in your original code, but (slightly) generalised so that we also have an `overF sumLengths` for lists of lists, for example.

```
import Data.Map as M hiding (map)
import qualified Control.Foldl       as CF
import Control.Foldl (Fold(..))
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Foldable as F
import Data.Maybe

--- the Fusable class:
class Functor f => Fusable f where
  fuseWith :: x -> (x -> a -> x) -> f x -> f a -> f x 
  emptyf   :: f a 

--- Map k is a Fusable (whenever k has an ordering)
instance (Ord k) => Fusable (Map k) where
   fuseWith x f xmap amap = M.foldrWithKey insert xmap amap where    
      insert k el xmap = M.insert k (f (fromMaybe x $ M.lookup k xmap) el) xmap 
   emptyf = M.empty

--- Lists are Fusable
instance Fusable [] where
  fuseWith  = zipWithDefault where
    zipWithDefault dx f [] ys = zipWith f (repeat dx) ys
    zipWithDefault dx f xs [] = xs
    zipWithDefault dx f (x:xs) (y:ys) = (f x y) : zipWithDefault dx f xs ys
  emptyf = []

--- The generalised overMaps:
overF :: (Fusable f) => Fold a b  -> Fold (f a) (f b)
overF (Fold step begin done) = Fold (fuseWith begin step) emptyf (fmap done)

--- some tests
testlist = [(1,4),(3,99),(7,999)]
testlist2 = [(1,15),(2,88)]

test  = CF.fold (overF CF.sum)  $ map fromList [testlist, testlist2] 
-- fromList [(1,19),(2,88),(3,99),(7,999)]
test2 = CF.fold (overF $ CF.premap snd CF.sum) [testlist, testlist2] 
-- [19,187,999]
```

If we don't worry about taking the `begin` value along, we can use any `Applicative` (`Map k` is not `Applicative`!)

```
overA :: (Applicative f) => Fold a b -> Fold (f a) (f b)
overA (Fold step begin done) = Fold (liftA2 step) (pure begin) (fmap done)
```

It certainly looks a lot like `overF`. But it gives different results: when folding over a list of lists, as soon as a list comes along that is too short, the result is truncated

```
test3 = CF.fold (overA $ CF.premap snd CF.sum) $  map ZipList [testlist, testlist2] 
-- ZipList [19,187]  -- *where* is my third element :-(
```